# can't split text by double new line in js

Tags: javascript, php

I want to split this text(song) by double new line, i get it from php using ajax(fetch API)

```
You sad me goodbye
You did let me see
Then you[[em]] let me bye
So you let[[F]] me bye
know this can be
You know[[em]] I don't lie
This happened to me

Remember - we[[D]] knew
I can't fit my mind
I'm feeling[[C]] so blue
Why you telling «bye»
So you let me bye
I know[[F]] this can be
You know I don't lie
This happened to me[[A]]

This happened to me[[A]]
You sad me[[A]] goodbye
You did let me see
Then you let me[[A]] bye
So you let[[EM]] me bye
I know this can be
You know I don't lie
This happened to me[[A]]"
```

i had tried next regex's, but non of it doesn't work in my js

```
/\n{2,}/g
/\n\r{2,}/
/\r\n{2,}|\r{2,}|\n{2,}/g
```

here is the line of code that shows how i use it

```
let paragraphs = text.split(/\r\n{2,}|\r{2,}|\n{2,}/g);
```

However on https://regex101.com/ they all works fine, any help would be appreciated, thank you!

P.S. headers in PHP already checked twice(JSON and UTF-8).

Comment: You're asumming that `\n` (single newline) is not a line break, because in your regex you're expecting that all line breaks have at least two `\n`?

Comment: yes, coz in Sonata bundle(Symfony 2.7+) i dont have opportunity to put editor, so user will enter just a plain text

Comment: `\r\n{2,}` is equal `\r{1}\n{2,}` . use  `(\r\n){2,}`

Comment: no, thats doesn't do a trick

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
text.split(/\n\s*\n/)
```

gives me next

```
[
"You sad me goodbye
You did let me see
Then you[[em]] let me bye
So you let[[F]] me bye
know this can be
You know[[em]] I don't lie
This happened to me", // <--
"Remember - we[[D]] knew
I can't fit my mind
I'm feeling[[C]] so blue
Why you telling «bye»
So you let me bye
I know[[F]] this can be
You know I don't lie
This happened to me[[A]]", // <--
"This happened to me[[A]]
You sad me[[A]] goodbye
You did let me see
Then you let me[[A]] bye
So you let[[EM]] me bye
I know this can be
You know I don't lie
This happened to me[[A]]""
]
```

`text.split(/\n\s*\n/).length // 3`

about your code

```
text.charCodeAt(151) // 10
text.charCodeAt(152) // 82 <--
'\n'.charCodeAt(0) // 10
'\r'.charCodeAt(0) // 13 <--
```

Comment: you mean that i'd missed possible spaces between?

Comment: @Smile0ff check with encodeURI(text),  also \s* covers \n|\r and spaces

Comment: encodeURIComponent(text) / encodeURI(text) - both show you hidden symbols

Comment: well, ty your regex is working fine, but i can't understand how to adapt it to 2 or more breaks

Comment: it contains 2 breaks ( at least )

Comment: oh yea, 0 or more, yea, sry

Comment: @Smile0ff check last section in my answer - it's about symbols between paragraphs